# Add a <select> after another <select> inside a dialog in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select>` inside a dialog and when I try my code I don't understand why it doesn't create my `<select>`.

```
      <select class="form-control agregation" name="agregation" id="select2">
        <option>Titres</option>
        <option>Indicateurs</option>
        <option>Catégories</option>
        <option>Données 12 mois Glissante</option>
      </select>



        var Mytab = [
           "Données",
           "Deplacement",
           "Validation"               
        ];

        $("<select id='byOptions'>").appendTo("#select2");
        $.each(Mytab , function(value) {
        $("#byOptions").append($("<option></option>")
           .attr("value", value).text(value));
        });
```

what is not good ?

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/te1ewhd9/)

Use `insertAfter()`

**Change**

```
$("<select id='byOptions'>").appendTo("#select2");
```

**To**

```
$("<select id='byOptions'>").insertAfter("#select2");
```

**Correct**

```
$("<select id='byOptions'>").insertAfter("#select2");
$.each(Mytab , function(index,value) {
              $("#byOptions").append($("<option></option>")
              .attr("value", value).text(value));
});
```

Comment: I did not know this function. Thanks!